# How to loop a function in Postman

Tags: postman

I was trying to write test the presence of each of the elements in each set. ex: Whether `familyName` is present in each set, or `firstName` is present in each set, and so on.

When I tried to use `to.have.property` function inside a loop (as below), I get the message `don't use function inside the loop`.

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
totalNumber = jsonData.length;

while (i < totalNumber) {
    i=0;
    pm.test('familyName is present in the response', function() {
        pm.expect(jsonData[i]).to.have.property('agentSSN');
        i++;
    }
)};
```

**Response sample:**

```
[
    {
        "familyName": "123",
        "firstName": "tester2",
        "middleName": "",
        "lastName": "test ",
        "ContactNumber1": "",
        "ContactNumber2": ""
    },
    {
        "familyName": "123",
        "firstName": "tester1",
        "middleName": "",
        "lastName": "test2",
        "ContactNumber1": "",
        "ContactNumber2": ""
    }

]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just try this:

```
pm.test('familyName is present in the response', () => {
    _.each(pm.response.json(), (item) => {
        pm.expect(item).to.have.property('agentSSN');
    })
})
```

It will iterate through the response and check to see if that `property` is in the object.

Comment: @Aan Can you accept this answer so it can be closed out please.

Comment: @Aan please hit the green tick next to Danny's answer if it solved your problem.